# anyway to add a bunch of input of csv files in this python program? I want to search by more than 15 csv files

Tags: python, csv, search, reader

```
import csv

def searchProxy():

Identifier = input("Enter proxy\n"_)
csv_file = csv.reader(open ('\Users\jwill\Documents\orderreport.CSV', 'r'))

for row Identifier in csv_file:
    ifIdentifier == row[0]:
            print(row)



print ('Enter to search identifier')

src = int(input ("Enter here: "))
```

So here the simple python program above search through a csv file's first row(identifier) and returns value if it's found.

How do I make changes so

1. I can search by more than 1 file, do I just add another file name location before the r?
2. how do I change the code so I can enter multiple input at the same time? Like 20 or 25 proxy at the same time to go through all the csv files. No identifier can exist in two csv file.

Also I have one error:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I didn't see that error when it was compile and run online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is because you have not indented after `def searchProxy():`

to do more than one file create a list for your input files, and loop over them.

```
filelist = ["a.csv","b.csv"]

for i in filelist:
    csv_file = csv.reader(open (i, 'r'))
```

---

```
identifierlist = ["x","y","z"]

for row Identifier in csv_file:
    for j in identifierlist:
        if j == row[0]:
            print(row)
        #OR

        if j in row[0]:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Can you please write an answer, I will accept it

Comment: also what does it mean not indented? just add a tab?

Comment: yes add a tab. what do you mean by multiple input?

Comment: like as for now, I'm just entering one identifier, if I want to search 5 different identifier in 20 different files.

Comment: I updated the answer. I'm not sure what your identifier is but one of those should work